# Not able to send keys

Tags: java, servlets, keystore

I want to transfer my keystore object from my server to the client application:

I am doing the following:

```
 response.reset();
 response.setBufferSize(10240);
 response.setContentType(contentType);
 response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(keystoreFile.length()));
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
 BufferedInputStream input = null;
 BufferedOutputStream output = null;
 try{


 input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
 output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

 output.write(KeyStoreUtil.getFileByteArray(input));
 }finally{
     input.close();
     output.close();
 }
```

But the file is getting corrupted in client end and getting error while fetching the keystore as:

```
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.ja
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(Jce
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
```

actually what i see is,file is getting created:
If I run the command from command prompt as:

```
keytool -list -storetype jceks -keystore aeskeystore.jck
Enter keystore password:
```

I get the error:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

getFileByteArray is as follows:

```
public static byte[] getFileByteArray(InputStream fileInputStream) {
    if (fileInputStream != null) {
        int readLine = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[16384];
        ByteArrayOutputStream fileBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            while ((readLine = fileInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                fileBuffer.write(data, 0, readLine);
            }

            return fileBuffer.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error occurred while reading keyfile::::"
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You aren't transferring an object, you are transferring a file. Obviously there is something wrong with KeyStoreUtil.getFileByteArray(), which you haven't posted for some reason, or else with the client code, ditto, but why are you transferring keystores? This is *prima facie* invalid and a security breach.

Comment: So now you've posted half the code that was missing and you haven't answered my question.